# Javascript, value on hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Problem:** Unable to get alert pop-up

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function suppression(id) {
        if(confirm("Supprimer ?")) {
            document.suppression.sup.value = id;
            alert('test');
            document.suppression.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

My form :

```
<form name="suppression" action="supprimer.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="sup">
</form>
```

I have a while with that :

```
<td>
  <button name='bouton_delete' value='SUPPRESSION' onclick='suppression(".$row['PID'].");return true;'>SUPPRESSION</button>
</td>
```

Comment: A (non)working example is very helpful for answering this type of question. Can you make a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: What does your js console throw?

Comment: where's this from? .$row['PID']

Comment: @satchcoder : my console return "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function -> onclick"

Comment: @Quannt : It's a value in the while, that it's ok : my code source on chrome : "<button name="bouton_delete" value="SUPPRESSION" onclick="suppression(24);return true;">SUPPRESSION</button>"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<td>
<button name='bouton_delete' value='SUPPRESSION' onclick='suppression(".$row['PID'].");return true;'>SUPPRESSION</button>
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
<button name='bouton_delete' value='SUPPRESSION' onclick='suppression(<?php echo ' . $row['PID'] . '; ?>);return true;'>SUPPRESSION</button>
</td>
```

See, if that solves your problem.

Comment: No, when i check my codesource, i have :

<button name="bouton_delete" value="SUPPRESSION" onclick="suppression(24);return true;">SUPPRESSION</button>

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, it was a conflict... Function 'suppression' and form 'suppression', i change for fun_suppression, now it's ok